# How to avoid "Forcing rebuild: JavaScript files need to be re-encrypted"

Tags: javascript, build, titanium, titanium-mobile, titanium-alloy

I'm using Titanium and I look for a way to make my app build faster so it won't take so long to test it every time. Even when I run it twice without adding anything, it takes about a minute to build and 10 more seconds to install on my device.

I think the key is in "Forcing rebuild: JavaScript files need to be re-encrypted".
Is there a way to avoid this rebuilding?

### Full log:

```
Titanium Command-Line Interface, CLI version 3.3.0, Titanium SDK version 3.3.0.GA
Copyright (c) 2012-2014, Appcelerator, Inc.  All Rights Reserved.
Please report bugs to http://jira.appcelerator.org/
[INFO] :   Found Titanium plugin id=ti.alloy version=1.0 
[INFO] :   Deploy type: test
[INFO] :   Building for target: device
[INFO] :   Building for device: 4df72fe56496cff9
[INFO] :   Targeting Android SDK: 19
[INFO] :   Building for the following architectures: armeabi, armeabi-v7a, x86
[INFO] :   Signing with keystore: C:\Users\Ella\AppData\Roaming\Titanium\mobilesdk\win32\3.3.0.GA\android\dev_keystore (tidev)
[INFO] :   Debugging disabled
[INFO] :   Profiler disabled
[INFO] :   Forcing rebuild: JavaScript files need to be re-encrypted
[INFO] :   Found Alloy app in C:\Users\Ella\Documents\Titanium_Studio_Workspace\FaveBooks\app
[INFO] :   Executing Alloy compile: alloy.cmd compile C:\Users\Ella\Documents\Titanium_Studio_Workspace\FaveBooks\app --config platform=android,version=0,simtype=none,devicefamily=none,deploytype=test,target=device --no-colors
[INFO]  [config.json] regenerating CFG.js from config.json...
[INFO] ----- MVC GENERATION -----
[INFO] [global style] loading from cache...
[INFO] [models/books.js] model processing...
[INFO] [addbook.xml] view processing...
[INFO]   style:      "addbook.tss"
[INFO]   view:       "addbook.xml"
[INFO]   controller: "addbook.js"
[INFO]   created:    "Resources\android\alloy\controllers\addbook.js"
[INFO]   created:     "Resources\android\alloy\styles\addbook.js"
[INFO] [bookdetails.xml] view processing...
[INFO]   style:      "bookdetails.tss"
[INFO]   view:       "bookdetails.xml"
[INFO]   controller: "bookdetails.js"
[INFO]   created:    "Resources\android\alloy\controllers\bookdetails.js"
[INFO]   created:     "Resources\android\alloy\styles\bookdetails.js"
[INFO] [index.xml] view processing...
[INFO]   style:      "index.tss"
[INFO]   view:       "index.xml"
[INFO]   controller: "index.js"
[INFO]   created:    "Resources\android\alloy\controllers\index.js"
[INFO]   created:     "Resources\android\alloy\styles\index.js"
[INFO] 
[INFO] [app.js] using cached app.js...
[INFO] 
[INFO] ----- OPTIMIZING -----
[INFO] - android\alloy.js
[INFO] - android\alloy\models\Books.js
[INFO] - android\alloy\sync\localStorage.js
[INFO] - android\alloy\sync\properties.js
[INFO] - android\alloy\sync\sql.js
[INFO] 
[INFO] Alloy compiled in 0.85472s
[INFO] :   Alloy compiler completed successfully
[WARN] :   Overwriting file C:\Users\Ella\Documents\Titanium_Studio_Workspace\FaveBooks\build\android\bin\assets\Resources\appicon.png
[WARN] :   Overwriting file C:\Users\Ella\Documents\Titanium_Studio_Workspace\FaveBooks\build\android\bin\assets\Resources\MarketplaceArtwork.png
[INFO] :   Processing JavaScript files
[INFO] :   Encrypting JavaScript files: C:\Users\Ella\AppData\Roaming\Titanium\mobilesdk\win32\3.3.0.GA\android\titanium_prep.win32.exe "com.ella.favebooks" "C:\Users\Ella\Documents\Titanium_Studio_Workspace\FaveBooks\build\android\assets" "app.js" "alloy/backbone.js" "alloy/CFG.js" "alloy/constants.js" "alloy/controllers/addbook.js" "alloy/controllers/BaseController.js" "alloy/controllers/bookdetails.js" "alloy/controllers/index.js" "alloy/models/Books.js" "alloy/styles/addbook.js" "alloy/styles/bookdetails.js" "alloy/styles/index.js" "alloy/sync/localStorage.js" "alloy/sync/properties.js" "alloy/sync/sql.js" "alloy/underscore.js" "alloy/widget.js" "alloy.js" "_app_props_.json"
[INFO] :   Writing C:\Users\Ella\Documents\Titanium_Studio_Workspace\FaveBooks\build\android\bin\assets\app.json
[INFO] :   Extracting module resources: C:\Users\Ella\AppData\Roaming\Titanium\mobilesdk\win32\3.3.0.GA\android\modules\titanium-analytics.res.zip
[INFO] :   Extracting module resources: C:\Users\Ella\AppData\Roaming\Titanium\mobilesdk\win32\3.3.0.GA\android\modules\titanium-android.res.zip
[INFO] :   Extracting module resources: C:\Users\Ella\AppData\Roaming\Titanium\mobilesdk\win32\3.3.0.GA\android\modules\titanium-app.res.zip
[INFO] :   Extracting module resources: C:\Users\Ella\AppData\Roaming\Titanium\mobilesdk\win32\3.3.0.GA\android\modules\titanium-filesystem.res.zip
[INFO] :   Extracting module resources: C:\Users\Ella\AppData\Roaming\Titanium\mobilesdk\win32\3.3.0.GA\android\modules\titanium-media.res.zip
[INFO] :   Extracting module resources: C:\Users\Ella\AppData\Roaming\Titanium\mobilesdk\win32\3.3.0.GA\android\modules\titanium-locale.res.zip
[INFO] :   Extracting module resources: C:\Users\Ella\AppData\Roaming\Titanium\mobilesdk\win32\3.3.0.GA\android\modules\titanium-network.res.zip
[INFO] :   Extracting module resources: C:\Users\Ella\AppData\Roaming\Titanium\mobilesdk\win32\3.3.0.GA\android\modules\titanium-xml.res.zip
[INFO] :   Extracting module resources: C:\Users\Ella\AppData\Roaming\Titanium\mobilesdk\win32\3.3.0.GA\android\modules\titanium-platform.res.zip
[INFO] :   Extracting module resources: C:\Users\Ella\AppData\Roaming\Titanium\mobilesdk\win32\3.3.0.GA\android\modules\titanium-database.res.zip
[INFO] :   No aidl files to compile, continuing
[INFO] :   Generating i18n files
[INFO] :   Generating C:\Users\Ella\Documents\Titanium_Studio_Workspace\FaveBooks\build\android\res\values\theme.xml
[INFO] :   Packaging application: C:\android\android-sdk\build-tools\20.0.0\aapt.exe "package" "-f" "-m" "-J" "C:\Users\Ella\Documents\Titanium_Studio_Workspace\FaveBooks\build\android\gen" "-M" "C:\Users\Ella\Documents\Titanium_Studio_Workspace\FaveBooks\build\android\AndroidManifest.xml" "-A" "C:\Users\Ella\Documents\Titanium_Studio_Workspace\FaveBooks\build\android\bin\assets" "-S" "C:\Users\Ella\Documents\Titanium_Studio_Workspace\FaveBooks\build\android\res" "-I" "C:\android\android-sdk\platforms\android-19\android.jar" "-I" "C:\Users\Ella\AppData\Roaming\Titanium\mobilesdk\win32\3.3.0.GA\android\titanium.jar" "-I" "C:\Users\Ella\AppData\Roaming\Titanium\mobilesdk\win32\3.3.0.GA\android\aps-analytics.jar" "-F" "C:\Users\Ella\Documents\Titanium_Studio_Workspace\FaveBooks\build\android\bin\app.ap_" "--auto-add-overlay" "--extra-packages" "ti.modules.titanium.ui:android.support.v7.appcompat" "-S" "C:\Users\Ella\AppData\Local\Temp\11479-4676-ix6nn7/res" "-S" "C:\Users\Ella\AppData\Local\Temp\11479-4676-1sttmy9/res"
[INFO] :   Building Java source files: C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.7.0_65\bin\javac.exe "-J-Xmx256M" "-encoding" "utf8" "-bootclasspath" "C:\android\android-sdk\platforms\android-19\android.jar;C:\Users\Ella\AppData\Roaming\Titanium\mobilesdk\win32\3.3.0.GA\android\kroll-v8.jar;C:\Users\Ella\AppData\Roaming\Titanium\mobilesdk\win32\3.3.0.GA\android\modules\titanium-analytics.jar;C:\Users\Ella\AppData\Roaming\Titanium\mobilesdk\win32\3.3.0.GA\android\aps-analytics.jar;C:\Users\Ella\AppData\Roaming\Titanium\mobilesdk\win32\3.3.0.GA\android\modules\titanium-android.jar;C:\Users\Ella\AppData\Roaming\Titanium\mobilesdk\win32\3.3.0.GA\android\jaxen-1.1.1.jar;C:\Users\Ella\AppData\Roaming\Titanium\mobilesdk\win32\3.3.0.GA\android\ti-commons-codec-1.3.jar;C:\Users\Ella\AppData\Roaming\Titanium\mobilesdk\win32\3.3.0.GA\android\kroll-common.jar;C:\Users\Ella\AppData\Roaming\Titanium\mobilesdk\win32\3.3.0.GA\android\titanium.jar;C:\Users\Ella\AppData\Roaming\Titanium\mobilesdk\win32\3.3.0.GA\android\modules\titanium-app.jar;C:\Users\Ella\AppData\Roaming\Titanium\mobilesdk\win32\3.3.0.GA\android\modules\titanium-ui.jar;C:\Users\Ella\AppData\Roaming\Titanium\mobilesdk\win32\3.3.0.GA\android\nineoldandroids-appc-2.4.0.jar;C:\Users\Ella\AppData\Roaming\Titanium\mobilesdk\win32\3.3.0.GA\android\modules\titanium-filesystem.jar;C:\Users\Ella\AppData\Roaming\Titanium\mobilesdk\win32\3.3.0.GA\android\modules\titanium-media.jar;C:\Users\Ella\AppData\Roaming\Titanium\mobilesdk\win32\3.3.0.GA\android\modules\titanium-appcompat.jar;C:\Users\Ella\AppData\Roaming\Titanium\mobilesdk\win32\3.3.0.GA\android\android-support-v4.jar;C:\Users\Ella\AppData\Roaming\Titanium\mobilesdk\win32\3.3.0.GA\android\android-support-v7-appcompat.jar;C:\Users\Ella\AppData\Roaming\Titanium\mobilesdk\win32\3.3.0.GA\android\modules\titanium-locale.jar;C:\Users\Ella\AppData\Roaming\Titanium\mobilesdk\win32\3.3.0.GA\android\modules\titanium-network.jar;C:\Users\Ella\AppData\Roaming\Titanium\mobilesdk\win32\3.3.0.GA\android\thirdparty.jar;C:\Users\Ella\AppData\Roaming\Titanium\mobilesdk\win32\3.3.0.GA\android\modules\titanium-xml.jar;C:\Users\Ella\AppData\Roaming\Titanium\mobilesdk\win32\3.3.0.GA\android\modules\titanium-platform.jar;C:\Users\Ella\AppData\Roaming\Titanium\mobilesdk\win32\3.3.0.GA\android\modules\titanium-database.jar;C:\Users\Ella\AppData\Roaming\Titanium\mobilesdk\win32\3.3.0.GA\android\lib\titanium-verify.jar;R.class;ApplicationStylesheet.class;AssetCryptImpl.class;MyBooksActivity.class;MyBooksAppInfo.class;MyBooksApplication.class" "-d" "C:\Users\Ella\Documents\Titanium_Studio_Workspace\FaveBooks\build\android\bin\classes" "-proc:none" "-target" "1.6" "-source" "1.6" "@C:\Users\Ella\Documents\Titanium_Studio_Workspace\FaveBooks\build\android\java-sources.txt"
[INFO] :   Running dexer: C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.7.0_65\bin\java.exe "-Xmx1024M" "-XX:-UseGCOverheadLimit" "-Djava.ext.dirs=C:\android\android-sdk\platform-tools" "-jar" "C:\android\android-sdk\build-tools\20.0.0\lib\dx.jar" "--dex" "--output=C:\Users\Ella\Documents\Titanium_Studio_Workspace\FaveBooks\build\android\bin\classes.dex" "C:\Users\Ella\Documents\Titanium_Studio_Workspace\FaveBooks\build\android\bin\classes" "C:\Users\Ella\AppData\Roaming\Titanium\mobilesdk\win32\3.3.0.GA\android\lib\titanium-verify.jar" "C:\Users\Ella\AppData\Roaming\Titanium\mobilesdk\win32\3.3.0.GA\android\kroll-v8.jar" "C:\Users\Ella\AppData\Roaming\Titanium\mobilesdk\win32\3.3.0.GA\android\modules\titanium-analytics.jar" "C:\Users\Ella\AppData\Roaming\Titanium\mobilesdk\win32\3.3.0.GA\android\aps-analytics.jar" "C:\Users\Ella\AppData\Roaming\Titanium\mobilesdk\win32\3.3.0.GA\android\modules\titanium-android.jar" "C:\Users\Ella\AppData\Roaming\Titanium\mobilesdk\win32\3.3.0.GA\android\jaxen-1.1.1.jar" "C:\Users\Ella\AppData\Roaming\Titanium\mobilesdk\win32\3.3.0.GA\android\ti-commons-codec-1.3.jar" "C:\Users\Ella\AppData\Roaming\Titanium\mobilesdk\win32\3.3.0.GA\android\kroll-common.jar" "C:\Users\Ella\AppData\Roaming\Titanium\mobilesdk\win32\3.3.0.GA\android\titanium.jar" "C:\Users\Ella\AppData\Roaming\Titanium\mobilesdk\win32\3.3.0.GA\android\modules\titanium-app.jar" "C:\Users\Ella\AppData\Roaming\Titanium\mobilesdk\win32\3.3.0.GA\android\modules\titanium-ui.jar" "C:\Users\Ella\AppData\Roaming\Titanium\mobilesdk\win32\3.3.0.GA\android\nineoldandroids-appc-2.4.0.jar" "C:\Users\Ella\AppData\Roaming\Titanium\mobilesdk\win32\3.3.0.GA\android\modules\titanium-filesystem.jar" "C:\Users\Ella\AppData\Roaming\Titanium\mobilesdk\win32\3.3.0.GA\android\modules\titanium-media.jar" "C:\Users\Ella\AppData\Roaming\Titanium\mobilesdk\win32\3.3.0.GA\android\modules\titanium-appcompat.jar" "C:\Users\Ella\AppData\Roaming\Titanium\mobilesdk\win32\3.3.0.GA\android\android-support-v4.jar" "C:\Users\Ella\AppData\Roaming\Titanium\mobilesdk\win32\3.3.0.GA\android\android-support-v7-appcompat.jar" "C:\Users\Ella\AppData\Roaming\Titanium\mobilesdk\win32\3.3.0.GA\android\modules\titanium-locale.jar" "C:\Users\Ella\AppData\Roaming\Titanium\mobilesdk\win32\3.3.0.GA\android\modules\titanium-network.jar" "C:\Users\Ella\AppData\Roaming\Titanium\mobilesdk\win32\3.3.0.GA\android\thirdparty.jar" "C:\Users\Ella\AppData\Roaming\Titanium\mobilesdk\win32\3.3.0.GA\android\modules\titanium-xml.jar" "C:\Users\Ella\AppData\Roaming\Titanium\mobilesdk\win32\3.3.0.GA\android\modules\titanium-platform.jar" "C:\Users\Ella\AppData\Roaming\Titanium\mobilesdk\win32\3.3.0.GA\android\modules\titanium-database.jar"
[INFO] :   Creating unsigned apk
[INFO] :   Processing C:\Users\Ella\Documents\Titanium_Studio_Workspace\FaveBooks\build\android\src
[INFO] :   Writing unsigned apk: C:\Users\Ella\Documents\Titanium_Studio_Workspace\FaveBooks\build\android\bin\app-unsigned.apk
[INFO] :   Using MD5withRSA signature algorithm
[INFO] :   Signing apk: C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.7.0_65\bin\jarsigner.exe "-sigalg" "MD5withRSA" "-digestalg" "SHA1" "-keystore" "C:\Users\Ella\AppData\Roaming\Titanium\mobilesdk\win32\3.3.0.GA\android\dev_keystore" "-storepass" "*******" "-signedjar" "C:\Users\Ella\Documents\Titanium_Studio_Workspace\FaveBooks\build\android\bin\My Books.apk" "C:\Users\Ella\Documents\Titanium_Studio_Workspace\FaveBooks\build\android\bin\app-unsigned.apk" "tidev"
[INFO] :   Aligning zip file: C:\android\android-sdk\build-tools\20.0.0\zipalign.exe "-v" "4" "C:\Users\Ella\Documents\Titanium_Studio_Workspace\FaveBooks\build\android\bin\My Books.apk" "C:\Users\Ella\Documents\Titanium_Studio_Workspace\FaveBooks\build\android\bin\My Books.apkz"
[INFO] :   Writing build manifest: C:\Users\Ella\Documents\Titanium_Studio_Workspace\FaveBooks\build\android\build-manifest.json
[INFO] :   Making sure the adb server is running
[INFO] :   Installing apk: C:\Users\Ella\Documents\Titanium_Studio_Workspace\FaveBooks\build\android\bin\My Books.apk
[INFO] :   Installing app on device: GT-I9300
[INFO] :   App successfully installed
[INFO] :   Starting app: com.ella.favebooks/.MyBooksActivity
[INFO] :   Application pid: 17851
[ERROR] :  Trace: error opening trace file: No such file or directory (2)
-- Start application log -----------------------------------------------------
[INFO] :   Project built successfully in 1m 3s 885ms
[INFO] :   TiApplication: (main) [0,0] checkpoint, app created.
[INFO] :   TiApplication: (main) [359,359] Titanium 3.3.0 (2014/07/11 12:36 787cd39)
[INFO] :   TiApplication: (main) [511,870] Titanium Javascript runtime: v8
[INFO] :   TiRootActivity: (main) [0,0] checkpoint, on root activity create, savedInstanceState: null
[WARN] :   V8Object: Runtime disposed, cannot set property 'userAgent'
[INFO] :   I/dalvikvm-heap: Grow heap (frag case) to 15.077MB for 1536016-byte allocation
[INFO] :   I/dalvikvm-heap: Grow heap (frag case) to 17.712MB for 2731536-byte allocation
[INFO] :   TiRootActivity: (main) [0,0] checkpoint, on root activity resume. activity = com.ella.favebooks.MyBooksActivity@426c9ff8
[INFO] :   dalvikvm: Total arena pages for JIT: 11
[INFO] :   dalvikvm: Total arena pages for JIT: 12
[INFO] :   dalvikvm: Total arena pages for JIT: 13
[INFO] :   dalvikvm: Total arena pages for JIT: 14
[INFO] :   dalvikvm: Total arena pages for JIT: 15
[INFO] :   dalvikvm: Total arena pages for JIT: 16
[INFO] :   dalvikvm: Total arena pages for JIT: 17
[INFO] :   dalvikvm: Total arena pages for JIT: 18
[INFO] :   No config.adapter.idAttribute specified for table "books"
[INFO] :   Adding "alloy_id" to uniquely identify rows
```

---

Any ideas?

Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried using [TiShadow](http://tishadow.yydigital.com/) ? It let's you build project once and then just push changes in JS file without rebuilding whole thing.

Answer (score 3):

Yep as @daniula said in the comment, [TiShadow](http://tishadow.yydigital.com/getting%20started) is the way to go.

Step 1:
$ npm install -g tishadow

Step 2 (Express mode), build your app with "--shadow" e.g.:
$ ti build -p ios --shadow

Now when you make changes to the app, your device will update within a few seconds.

You can also run on multiple devices/simulators at the same time:

1. do step 1 above
2. create the tishadow app: $ mkdir ~/tishadowapp && tishadow app -d ~/tishadowapp
3. install the tishadow app on all of your devices e.g.: $ titanium build -p iphone -T device -F universal
4. run the tishadow server: $ tishadow server
5. open the tishadow app on your device/simulator and click "connect", type in e.g. "localhost" or the IP of your machine
6. open a new tab and type: $ tishadow @ run --update

Now every time you make a change, the devices will all automatically update in a few seconds

Comment: At step 5 on a physical device (iPhone 4s) I always get an alert "connect failed, could not connect to server" any ideas?

Comment: nevermind, it randomly started working after reverting to my first config after testing a bunch of different configs. probably a bad cable.